# Why doesn't SQL Server allow me to enable the mixed authentication mode so I can use the sa user to assign roles to the other users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs, ssms

I am trying to install TFS on the server but it requires to have the user SYSADMIN role which can only be assigned using the `sa` user login.

I am using SQL Server 2014 Express. To enable the `sa` user, I tried enabling the mixed mode authentication but I get this error:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_instance_regwrite', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

How do I fix that?

Update:

The problem is that I am Windows User and logging in with windows authentication. So using that user I am not able to assign any roles to myself or other user.

Comment: *"which can only be assigned using the sa user login."* This isn't true, it can be assigned by anyone with the `sysadmin` Server Role.

Comment: @Larnu hi, the problem is that I am Windows User and logging in with windows authentication. So using that user I am not able to assign any roles to myself or other user.

Comment: Then you need to speak to someone who does have the right privileges. Your permissions are limited for a reason; you shouldn't have `sysadmin` privileges if you don't require them. Speak to your DBA about setting up the needed login and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an existing installation of SQL Server for Azure DevOps Server/TFS. To do so, you need administrative credentials granted by the SQL Server administrator. You must be a member of the **sysadmin** server role in SQL Server to install and configure Azure DevOps Server/TFS. So you need to contact SQL Server administrator and grant your account appropriate permission to install Azure DevOps Server/TFS.

If you want to start a new installation of SQL Server, you could refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/sql-server/install-sql-server?view=azure-devops

[image]

Comment: we don't have a dba so I will have to assign so how do I do that?

Comment: In order to resolve your access issue, we recommend that you start the instance of SQL Server in single-user mode. This mode prevents other connections from occurring while you try to regain access. From here, you can connect to your instance of SQL Server and add your login to the sysadmin server role. Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: Kindly let us know your result. If you still can not access sql server, you would need to reinstall the instance.